# How do I clean previous markers (googleMaps.marker)

Tags: google-maps-markers, marker

I working on a small Google Maps project with jquerymobile.

First, I call un method to display the map regarding my position

```js
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){
        showMap(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
    }, 
    function onFalid(){
        alert('Error occur on getCurrentPositionError' + error.code + ':: ' + error.message);
    }, 
    {
        enableHighAccuracy  : true,
        maximumAge          : 10000
    });
```

Here is the code of showMap()

```js
function showMap(lat,long){

    //var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[0].coords.latitude, data[0].coords.longitude);
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long);

    // Google Map options
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 15,
      zoomControl   : 1,
      center: latLng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID////ROADMAP, SATELLITE, HYBRID and TERRAIN
    };

    // Create the Google Map, set options
    Tracking.mapy = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("mapHome"), myOptions);
    addMarker(lat, long, map);

}
```

This worked fine!

As you can see, at the end, it calls another method to display the marker

```js
function addMarker(lat, long){
    
    //Tracking.mapy.removeOverlay(Tracking.marker);;
    var mapBounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    
    var latitudeAndLongitude = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, long);
    var image = Markers.info()[0][1]+Markers.info()[0][2];
    
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        title   : Markers.info()[0][0],
        //animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP, //BOUNCE
        position: latitudeAndLongitude,
        map     : Tracking.mapy,
        icon : image
    });
    
    Tracking.markers.push(marker);
    
    // Clean previous markers THIS IS NOT WORKING!!!!!!!
    //google.maps.Map.prototype.clearOverlays = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < Tracking.markers.length; i++ ) {

        Tracking.markers[i].setMap(null);
        console.log(Tracking.markers[i]);
      }
    //}
    
    mapBounds.extend(latitudeAndLongitude);
    Tracking.mapy.fitBounds(mapBounds);
    //trackPath();
}
```

This works fine as well, except for the loop to clean the marker.

To make the thing more complicated, when I work in the street, I would like to see my marker moving, eighter instantly or frequently (egal)

The I add that call, just below the first code, I provided you:

```js
var track_id = Markers.info()[0][0];
    Tracking.watch_id = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
    // Success
    function(position){
        var lat = position.coords.latitude;
        var long = position.coords.longitude;
        
        Tracking.data.push(lat, long);
        addMarker(lat, long);
    
    },
    // Error
    function(error){
        alert('Error occur on watchPositionError' + error.code + ':: ' + error.message);
    },
    // Settings
    { 
        frequency: 3000, 
        enableHighAccuracy: true 
    });
```

Then each time, I am movie the array Tracking.markers will increment

```js
Tracking = {
    mapy : null,
    watch_id : null,    
    data : new Array(),
    markers : new Array()
}
```

**My Problem is here**
When I move on the street, I can see my markers. The more I move more I have markers. Of course, I just would like to have the last marker and not to have twin and new twins.

How can I clean the previous markers?
As you can see, above, I tried a loop

```js
// Clean previous markers
    //google.maps.Map.prototype.clearOverlays = function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < Tracking.markers.length; i++ ) {

        Tracking.markers[i].setMap(null);
        console.log(Tracking.markers[i]);
      }
    //}
```

But it did not work. If I uncomment the line starting by google.maps..., nothing works.
If I leave it commented, all marker a removed. So I can see any marker...

Could you help me to have my marker display where I am located following my move?